# Where can I find //html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js in my website?

Tags: css, wordpress, https

so, when scanning my website at sucuri.net, i get the following mixed content error

> "HTTPS mixed content found. Your HTTPS website is referring to an HTTP
>   resource: http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"

I've searched for this link in .php files but couldn't find anything

I've tried looking online for a similiar error but i'm only getting generic troubleshoot pages

Answer (score 0):

a) The error message is telling you that your site, which is served using the https:// (secure) protocol, has requested an asset specifying the http:// (non-secure) protocol, which is a violation and has been rejected. Easy enough to fix - make sure all your URLs to external resources have the protocol removed (e.g. //example.com instead of https://example.com) to ensure all links follow the same protocol as your site.

b) That actual link does no longer exist, but the replacement seems to be "//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" according to [this link](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1898). Happy coding!